# Php decoding Jsonarray from jsonobject

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, getjson

Hi i am working on php webservices and i am stucked with receving jsonarray as post request . i am able to receve other objects apart from jsonarray easily. My json structure looks like the following

```
{
    "full_name" :"amn",
    "phone":"9902",
    "educational_details":[
    {"board":"a","grade":"b","percentage":"21.0"},
    {"board":"a1","grade":"b1","percentage":"22.0"}
    ]
}
```

Here is my following php code to decode json

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

          $fullname=$data['full_name'];           
          $phone=$data['phone'];
          $email=$data['email'];
          $nativeaddress=$data['native_address'];
          $fresher=$data['fresher'];
          $skills=$data['skills'];
          $resumeUri=$data['resume_uri'];
          $obj = $data['educational_details'];

          $obj1=json_decode($obj,true);

          echo "arrayval".$obj1;
```

Any Help would be much appreciated.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: When you mean you're stuck, what exactly is not working? Have you checked your server logs for any error messages?

Comment: it says -->   <b>Warning</b>:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\s

Comment: check you file_get_contents('php://input') returning proper json

Comment: Ditto that. Try assigning the file contents into a variable and `var_dump` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution as given by someone above and worked perfectly

```
foreach($obj as $val){
              echo "<br>Board = " .$val['board']." <br>Grade = ".$val['grade'] ."<br> Percentage =".$val['percentage'];
                             $board=$val['board'];
                             $grade=$val['grade'];
                             $percentage=$val['percentage'];
                             $percentageval = floatval($percentage);
}
```

Comment: a small issue now ..$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);  $obj1=json_decode($data,true);
    
     $obj = $data['educational_details'];  the error displays as --->json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given And it gets inserted in database